# Django Timezone Issue

Tags: django

so I have `model` with a `DateTimeField`. Now when I store it in the database it gives me the correct time. However, when I print out the time, the time is ahead by 4 hours. This is probably due to some timezone issue. So I did some research and in my `settings.py` I have set a timezone:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Canada/Eastern'
```

But it still  doesn't work. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

EDIT: How I define the field: `Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Comment: how do you print it out?

Comment: print(object.Date) because, the field is called `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mysql/SQLite, as database doesn't store timezone info, so, after you defined timezone in `settings.py`, Django will convert your local time to UTC time each time before insert into the database. Don't worry, each time before you use this DateTime filed,Django would convert it back to local time automatically.
I don't know if this explanation can solve your problem.Also,remember define `USE_TZ =True` in `settings.py`.